# Using mysql and mongodb together for Django

Tags: django, relational-database, django-nonrel, non-relational-database

Can I use both relational-database(eg : mysql) and non-relational database(eg : mongodb) together as bacekend dbs for a Django project? If possible then how?
I use `Django version 1.11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, kind of. MongoDB is not supported as a backend for Django's ORM, however, you can use through MongoDB Python.

What I would do, in this case, is use MySQL as your `default` database in your `DATABASES` setting. I would use MySQL for all of my Django ORM functions, and only use MongoDB where I need it. You can then connect to MongoDB for non-ORM connections via Python. See here for connecting to MongoDB via Python: https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.4.0/

There used to be a Mongo backend - again, without much ORM support - but last I saw, it hasn't been updated in several years: https://github.com/django-nonrel

Good luck!

Comment: What are Django ORM functions exactly?

Comment: The Django ORM translates typically database tasks such as CRUD operations (Create, Retrieve, Update, Delete) from directly in Python without having to write SQL. This is typically done by manipulating a Python object. For example, if I have a class called `Book`, I can retrieve records with something like `my_books = Books.objects.filter(title__startswith='Hitchhiker')`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.